# Why is my form submitting when I don't want it to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want my form to submit only if the fields are filled out. At the moment it is submitting regardless of the outcome of the `submit` function below.

```
$("#findmusicians").submit(function(e)
{
    if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() && $('#message').val() != '')
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('fill in all fields');
    }
});
```

What else is triggering it?

Here's the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="findmusicians">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control required" minlength="1" id="inputName">
            <div id="hidden"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="email" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Telephone</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputTelephone" class="form-control" id="inputTelephone">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputInstrument" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Instrument(s)</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputInstrument" class="form-control" id="inputInstrument">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFee" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Fee</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" name="inputFee" class="form-control" id="inputFee">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Message</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="3" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
            <span class="help-block" style="text-align: left;">Please include as much information as possible including repertoire, rehearsal/performance times and venues.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
            <button id="findmusicians-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit request</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px">
        <span id="result" class="text-success"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### EXPLANATION

Currently the event *bubbles up* from within your `.submit` callback, what basically happens is that the default submit routine is still being fired.

You can prevent this by calling `e.preventDefault ()` from within your callback, to make sure that your event handler is the last to receive the event.

---

#### MODIFIED SNIPPET

```
$("#findmusicians").submit(function(e)
{
    if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() && $('#message').val() != '')
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('fill in all fields');
        e.preventDefault () // stop the event
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After `alert('fill in all fields');` you have to call `preventDafault()` to stop the form submit event or just put `return false;` after `alert('fill in all fields');` to stop form submit:

```
$("#findmusicians").submit(function(e)
{
    if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() && $('#message').val() != '')
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('fill in all fields');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `required` if you want to check the empty fields

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="findmusicians">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="inputName" required>
       </div>  
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```